# IIS Express port changes driving me crazy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-express

I always hated cassini.  I always loved using straight up IIS for a few reasons.  First off I'm working with a tool I should know, IIS and now I know it well. Second is dealing with the stupid dynamic ports with even IIS Express.  Plus cassini did some weird stuff so I don't like working in a black hole.

Anyway, I'm tired of having to change ports for IIS Express.  The guys here at work insist on not using straight up IIS and say it's just easier to fire up and use IIS express.  Well sure anything can be easier but is it the best thing to do?  I say no.

Is there any way to somehow get around this dynamic port issue when using IIS Express and be able to just somehow get it to work for everyone?  Even if I forced a certain port, the problem is some of my unit tests reference a port (JS Unit tests) or other things such as some WCF settings so I have to keep changing the port every time I stop or start the service becaue IIS express assigns a completely different port every time.

Comment: this may be of some help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not the best solution but works for me. Just go to Properties (in project) -> Web and set up IIS Express to the port you want.